# how to make a response to the inline query in telegram bot with unreal4u telegram api

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm using unreal4u telegram-API package. I want to send the result of an inline query I do the same that the package owner said but the response that the code makes don't respond that it's supposed to.

```php
  public function handleInlineQuery($inlineQuery)
    {
        //handel inline queries return
        $answerInlineQuery = new AnswerInlineQuery();
        $answerInlineQuery->inline_query_id = $inlineQuery->id;
        $answerInlineQuery->switch_pm_text = 'login';

        $inlineQueryResultArticle = new Article();
        $inlineQueryResultArticle->id = $inlineQuery->id;

        $text = new Text();
        $text->message_text = $inlineQuery->query;
        $inlineQueryResultArticle->input_message_content = $text;

        $answerInlineQuery->addResult($inlineQueryResultArticle);

        

        return $answerInlineQuery;
    }
```

## the response that i got :

it dont have the article that i made.

```
{
    "inline_query_id": "523656784772058542",
    "cache_time": 300,
    "is_personal": false,
    "next_offset": "",
    "switch_pm_text": "login",
    "switch_pm_parameter": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of the mentioned library. I would like to maintain GitHub for now as the place to answer questions, so I've answered it over there: https://github.com/unreal4u/telegram-api/issues/101

Greetings and thanks!